# Why does Google Chrome ignore "top" css property in a relatively-positioned element inside a flex-box?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, layout, cross-browser

Google Chrome, somewhere between version 80 and 84 seems to have made breaking changes to its layout engine, causing the HTML below to be rendered differently than before. It is also different than Firefox (v78) or Edge (v18).

```html
<head>
    <style>
        body { font-family: sans-serif; }
        .inner { border: 1px solid black; }
        .outer { display: flex; }
        span { position: relative; top: 50%; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <span>Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Google Chrome v84 renders this as:
[image: Google Chrome rendering ignores "top" property]

Firefox, Edge, and Google Chrome <= v80 render it like this:
[image: Other browsers and previous Chrome rendering uses "top" property]

Although the latter rendering appears "uglier", it is actually what I expect the result to be (based on Firefox, Edge, and Chrome's *previous* behavior). That is, I expect the text to be shifted down by 50%, relative to its containing `div`, due to the `top: 50%` css property. But Chrome's rendering doesn't seem to change whether `top` is specified or not.

However, I want to point out that when viewing Chrome's and Firefox's DevTools, the values for all layout attributes appear to be the same, including `top` (which is shown as 9px in both). So although Chrome seems to be interpreting the layout the same way nominally, the rendering is different.

This change in rendering (and difference between browsers) has caused a number of problems in the layout of a website that uses `top: 50%` in combination with `transform: translateY(-50%)` in order to center a block vertically within another block-positioned element -- a "classic" recipe, as described by [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_center-vertical.asp), [LogRocket](https://blog.logrocket.com/13-ways-to-vertical-center/) and others, e.g. [here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/). One difference between the classic recipe and what I have above is that the `span` is positioned `relative` instead of absolute. This allows the height and width of the `div.inner` to be based on the preferred size of the `span`. This was all working very nicely before the recent Chrome update.

If anyone can explain the difference in rendering or discuss the recent layout changes in Chrome and/or a workaround to achieve a consistent layout in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It's a bug. These things happen. It's fixed in Chrome canary (v86).

Comment: @Alohci - Thanks for the information. Can you elaborate? Do you have an issue number or other documentation that it's a bug? Can you post it as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have a bug number. Or a workaround. As a guess, it works something like this: When the height of the .outer flex container is auto, its height is taken from the total height of its content. including the span. So that gets laid out, and only then does the browser know how to compute 50% for the top value. It can then shift the span down accordingly. Chrome, maybe as an attempted optimisation, is trying to shortcut that process, and overdoing it, skipping the shift down entirely. You'll notice that if you give the .outer flex container a height in e.g. px, the layout works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1106074) on Chrome 84 that is being fixed at the moment.

Comment: That's it. Thanks: "Issue 1106074: Chrome 84 does not appear to consistently relatively position HTML content inside a flex cell"

Comment: fixed on Version 84.0.4147.105 that I already got from auto-updates BTW

Comment: @AlfaTeK I have Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (on Linux) and that bug is still present, relative positioning does not works within flexbox containers